# Applescript-objc - accessing class properties

Tags: applescript-objc

If I have a class `BFLocation` and I pass an array of those objects into my applescript-objc, how do I access the class properties?

BFLocation.h

```
@property NSString *url;
```

BFManager.h

```
#import "BFLocation.h"

@interface script : NSObject

- (void)processLocations:(NSArray *)locations;

@end
```

BFManager.applescript

```
script BFManager

property parent : class "NSObject"

on processLocations_(locations)
    repeat with location in locations
         log location's url
    end repeat
end processLocations
```

I get
`<NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'obj '{ 'form':'prop', 'want':'prop', 'seld':'url ', 'from':'obj '{ 'form':'ID  ', 'want':'ocid', 'seld':'optr'($C0FF060080610000$), 'from':null() } }>`

Do I need to cast location so it knows it's a `BFLocation` object?  Why am I getting an NSAppleEventDescriptor instead of the expected string?

Answer (score 0):

Did not have the syntax correct, should be

`location's |url|()`